# How set slotLabelFormat use constant

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar, typescript-typings

I try to set slotLabelFormat options in react typescript project

In case `slotLabelFormat={{ hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", omitZeroMinute: false, meridiem: "short" }}`
typescript compiled and all work fine

But if I set constant like

```
const SLOT_LABEL_FORMAT = { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", omitZeroMinute: false, meridiem: "short" };
```

and try set

```
slotLabelFormat={SLOT_LABEL_FORMAT}
```

typescript don't compiled and have errors

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in src/Calendar/Calendar/components/CalendarView.tsx:119:9

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: CalendarOptions | Readonly<CalendarOptions>): FullCalendar', gave the following error.
    Type '{ hour: string; minute: string; omitZeroMinute: boolean; meridiem: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FormatterInput | FormatterInput[] | undefined'.
      Type '{ hour: string; minute: string; omitZeroMinute: boolean; meridiem: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NativeFormatterOptions'.
        Types of property 'meridiem' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | "short" | "lowercase" | "narrow" | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CalendarOptions, context: any): FullCalendar', gave the following error.
    Type '{ hour: string; minute: string; omitZeroMinute: boolean; meridiem: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FormatterInput | FormatterInput[] | undefined'.
    117 |         allDaySlot={false}
    118 |         locale="uk"
  > 119 |         slotLabelFormat={SLOT_LABEL_FORMAT}
        |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    120 |         weekNumberCalculation="ISO" // Makes week calendar to start from monday
    121 |         slotMinWidth={72} // This property doesn't work (Fixed with styles)
    122 |         longPressDelay={50}
If try describe types for const will not expected result
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the object literal as a prop, it knows to treat it as `CalendarOptions` and the object property "meridian" is narrowed to the literal type `"short"`.

When you define the object beforehand, outside the context of the component prop, TypeScript infers the type of the object more broadly, and the type of "meridian" is instead `string`.

As you can see from the error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | "short" | "lowercase" | "narrow" | undefined'.
```

an arbitrary string is not an acceptable value for this property.

You can instruct the compiler to infer the type of your object as narrowly as possible by using a const assertion, and then it should work as you want:

```
const SLOT_LABEL_FORMAT = { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", omitZeroMinute: false, meridiem: "short" } as const;
```

This causes each string property to be typed as its string literal value rather than `string`.